# Loopback Passwords Migration: Use old system password for login or automatically create new one

Tags: loopbackjs

My system is running with a simple php/mysql arquitecture.

I'm currently creating a new REST api using loopback, which will be accessed through angular / ionic app. I'm pretending to use the loopback authentication system, but I don't know how to reuse my old system login/password, instead of registering a new user for each old one.

As far as I thought, There could be two ways:

- Use the login / old fashioned hashed value of password stored in my existing user (overriding the loopback hash password).
- Automatically create a new loopback user using existing credentials when the user logs in the existing system. (this option will require that the user logs in the old system at least one time before using the new api... It's alright for me)

Both options are fine for me as my users will continue to use same credentials for old and new system.

But I don't have any idea how can this be done in loopback.

Comment: Both are possible, which one do you favor and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I did not try any of them, which one do you think is the easier, cleaner ? And I don't know where to start...

Comment: Actually, there may be one thing preventing you to use option 1. Do you have the exact equivalent hashing function in javascript that you used to generate the hash with php ? Otherwise you won't be able to validate entered passwords against the hashes in the database

Comment: I have the exact hashing function.

Answer (score 0):

Succefully implemented the first option: overriding the loopback verifying password function.

1 - I've created a new userLoopback table in my database, using the loopback User model. 
(I could not use my existing table because no property name was matching loopback one, and I didn't want to mess it up. A little script copied needed data from existing user table to the new userLoopback table).

2 - I've created a new model in loopback based on buildin User model.

Has [overdrivr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4218017/overdrivr) says, you must have the same hashing method available in JS to succefully match stored password.

That's it...

**SQL for creating table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `userLoopback` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `realm` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `credentials` text,
  `challenges` text,
  `email` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `emailVerified` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verificationToken` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1211 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**userloopback.js**

```
module.exports = function(UserLoopback) {

  UserLoopback.prototype.hasPassword = function ( plain, fn ) {

    fn = fn || utils.createPromiseCallback();

    var user = this;

    if ( this.password ===   \\ hashed plain password \\ ) {
      return fn(null, true);
    }

    return fn(null, false);
  };
};
```